# Profile Field for 'visited' shows calendar dating pre-history of stackexchange

Tags: bug, status-declined, profile-page, visited-days

1. Go to your profile page.
2. Hover mouse on value for 'visited' field.

For example: visited   153 days. Hover mouse on 153 number.

3. Click on that number.
4. Calendar pops up.
5. Try to go before your join date.
6. If the calendar still shows dates, it does not make sense.

(The user is not interested in his past visits which goes past his join date)

7. Try to go before 2009 ( launching of StackExchange  )
8. If the calendar still shows dates, it does not make sense.

(The user is not interested in visits made when StackExchange was not even born)

Comment: If you are not interested in these dates, why go there?

Comment: I wouldn't call that a bug.

Comment: Is this really a bug? Isn't it just a calendar of all time with relevant data added. What problems are caused by allowing the calendar to show these dates?

Comment: It is not a bug. The primary objective of the calendar pop up is to show the visits on per-day basis.  It can be improved like: Calendar need not show dates before he has joined. Calendar need not show dates before StackExchange was existing.

Comment: Ok, I ask the calendar,  who's primary function is to provide visited dates whether jan 1st 2003 was a monday. Not its main function certainly but still useful. It can either (a) say; o thats a tuesday. Or (b) saying "no! Why you say? Because screw you! Thays why!"

Comment: thanks for teaching some lessons today... ( I am not desiring a vote here for the comment )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This doesn't seem like a problem. It's a calendar,  its default behaviour is to display all of time (within reason) and then add detail to that.

The question is who is being confused by this behaviour. Everyone knows time existed before stack exchange, so to put developer time into pretending that isn't the case seems pointless. Further more anyone who clicked that far back (for whatever reason) wanted a calender from then. I see no reason to refuse them that calender;  if you don't want to go back that far: don't.

Comment: maybe I need to learn how to tell what is wrong in software and how to spot what is actually wrong in software

Answer (score 7):

Suggested solution:

```
btnGoBack.Click += btnGoBack_Click;

void btnGoBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (user.Id == "gansai"
         && calendar.Month < user.RegisterationDate.Month)
         return;   //user says he is not interested
     else
         ActNormal();
}
```

Comment: It is funny.. Maybe I am too serious about what is shown.. I felt it was wrong to present calendars like that. Ok. Fine. Why So Serious??...

Comment: @gansai glad you liked my solution ;)

Comment: hey. i did not like it actually. someone else liked it. Ok. I am liking it now. :)

Comment: I bet that's C# psuedo coded

Comment: @puretppc Isn't that language sexy?

Comment: Yeah that's why I'm learning it lol. It's way better than Java!